# Sed command to break comma separated string upto certain length

Tags: sed

Example string

```
TEST,TEST1,TEST3,TEST4,TEST5
```

Expected output :

```
TEST,TEST1, 
TEST3,TEST4,
TEST5
```

I want to split data from comma before 15th position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 's/.\{,15\},/&\n/g' <<< "string" # or
sed 's/.\{,15\},/&\n/g' file
```

- `.\{,15\},` matches a part of input consisting of 0 to 15 characters followed by a comma. since `sed` is *greedy* while matching patterns, it will match as much characters as it can.
- `&\n` expands up to matched part followed by a line feed.
- `s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/g` replaces every match against `REGEXP` with `REPLACEMENT`.